# How can I avoid formatted cells which doesnt have values while converting excel file to pdf

Tags: java, itext

I am using itextpdf for this. And I got pdf corresponding to the excel file. But the 2nd sheet is formatted using formula. 1000 cells are formatted like this, but only 20 cells have values right now. So when I convert excel file to pdf ,then whole formatted cells are displaying in excel file. How can I avoid these empty cells from pdf?

Answer (score 0):

You could use jexcel to see if the current cell you are accessing has contents present or not..

```
       File xls=new File("url of excel file");
        try {

            Workbook wb=Workbook.getWorkbook(xls);
            for(int shno=0;shno<wb.getNumberOfSheets();shno++)
            {   Sheet s=wb.getSheet(shno);
                int rows=s.getRows();
                for(int i=0;i<rows;i++) {
                    data=s.getCell(1,i).getContents();

            }
```

Now using data add it to your pdf file...
Hope this helps. :)

Comment: How to avoid the cells which contains only formula not data.

Comment: it's inputted in the excel as a string i believe?? Then you wont face any problem... Could you please explain your question in detail??

Comment: I have 4 sheets in ma excel file.in 1st 2nd and 4th am inputting the string and numeric value..but in 3rd sheet am using formula for getting values from 2nd sheet..100- rows in 3rd sheet is formatted.The pdf is generated ,but the 3rd sheet pdf showing all 1000 blank rows even if only 20 rows are filled...i need to avoid these blank rows